# Google SDK local addresses in local language

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

It works with english languages but doesn't work with russian launguage. Why? Google maps allows to input local language in my country.

```
let geocoder1 = CLGeocoder()


    let address1 = "улица Здолбуновская 7г, Киев"
    geocoder1.geocodeAddressString(address1) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            println("No found address")

        }

        else if let placemarks = placemarks {
            if placemarks.count != 0 {
                println(placemarks.first!)

            }
        }
    }

    let geocoder2 = CLGeocoder()

    let address2 = "Zdolbunivska St, 7H, Kyiv, Ukraine"
    geocoder2.geocodeAddressString(address2) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            println("No found address")
        }

        else if let placemarks = placemarks {
            if placemarks.count != 0 {
                println(placemarks.first!)

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found one solution - use Yandex - it works perfectly with russian addresses

https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/

I found pod

https://github.com/exister/YandexGeocoder.

I take address via YandexGecoder and use google map to put point on map

Comment: Without any code it doesn't count as a solution to me.

Comment: try put Yandex geocoder in Google. Sometimes need to do something :)